# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Tags: python, model, regression, data-science, logistic-regression

I'm a beginner in Data Science and I'm currently working on building a model for the IBM Employee Attrition Dataset. How do I get around this error?

```
# LogisticRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#Copy the DataFrame
df1 = df.copy()

#Convert categorical variables to numeric 
dummy_df = pd.get_dummies(df1, columns=["Attrition", "BusinessTravel", "Department", "EducationField", 
                                        "Gender", "JobRole", "OverTime", "MaritalStatus"], drop_first = True)
dummy_df = pd.concat([df1, dummy_df], axis=1)

dummy_df = dummy_df.drop(["Attrition", "BusinessTravel", "Department", "EducationField", 
                                        "Gender", "JobRole", "OverTime", "MaritalStatus"], axis=1)

dummy_df.rename({"Attrition_Yes":"Attrition", "OverTime_Yes":"OverTime"}, axis=1, inplace=True)

#Drop duplicate columns
dummy_df = dummy_df.loc[:,~dummy_df.columns.duplicated()]

X = dummy_df.drop("Attrition", axis=1).values

y = dummy_df["Attrition"].values


X_train, X_test,  y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=15, stratify=y)

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)

logreg.score(y_pred, y_test)

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably sending a `pandas series` instead of a `dataframe`. Instead of `df['column']` send `df[['column']]`. If it doesn't work, please supply code.

Comment: Please have a look at the code. It has been supplied.